# Не могу получить значение из шаблонного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

```
template <typename El> class MyArray
{
    //...
    El & MyArray<El>::operator[](int i)
    {
        return this->internal_array[i];
    }
}
```

В мэйне я его объявляю как 
MyArray *a = new MyArray();Но при попытке присвоить по индексу (int b = a[0]) получаю ошибку

> E0413  не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "MyArray" в "int"

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор [] должен вызывается для объекта, а не для указателя на него, иначе вы обращаетесь по сути к массиву из `MyArray<int>`. Т.е. вам либо нужно создавать локальный объект (без new), либо получать ссылку на него:

```
MyArray<int> array1; // Локальный объект
int r1 = array1[1];

MyArray<int>* array2_ptr = new MyArray<int>; // Динамический объект
int r2 = (*array2_ptr)[1];

MyArray<int>& array2_ref = *array2_ptr;
r2 = array2_ref[i];

delete array2_ptr;
```

Если вы хотите выделять объекты в динамической памяти, лучше использовать умные указатели:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyArray<int>> array3_ptr = new MyArray<int>; // Удаляется автоматически
int r3 = (*array3_ptr)[1];
```

Comment: >Удаляется автоматически   Когда и при каких условиях?

Comment: @AntonyRed, в случае `unique_ptr` при выходе указателя из области видимости, но объект можно перемещать между указателями. В случае `shared_ptr` на один объект могут указывать несколько указателей, объект удаляется при обнулении счетчика ссылок. `weak_ptr` - не владеющий указатель, позволяет избежать циклических ссылок для `shared_ptr`. Подробнее про них нужно гуглить отдельно, в двух словах не расскажешь.